# better way to implement function that takes [Maybe a] and returns Maybe [a]

Tags: haskell, option-type

I need a function that takes [Maybe a] list as an input, picks up each value, process it and return Maybe [a]. I want to return Nothing if the input list has a Nothing.

```
func [Just 1,Just 2,Just 3,Just 4,Just 5] => this returns Just [1,2,3,4,5]
func [Just 1,Nothing,Just 3,Just 4,Just 5] => this returns Nothing
```

I wrote this

```
func mlist = if elem Nothing mlist
             then Nothing
             else Just $ map (\(Just e) -> e) mlist
```

It works but I am wondering if I can do it better. I don't like the part where I do elem Nothing mlist first and map the mlist again.

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BMaybe+a%5D+->+Maybe+%5Ba%5D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality already exists with the [**`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) function:

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [Just 3]
Just [3]
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [Just 3, Nothing]
Nothing
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [Just 3, Just 2]
Just [3,2]
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [Just 1,Just 2,Just 3,Just 4,Just 5]
Just [1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [Just 1,Nothing,Just 3,Just 4,Just 5]
Nothing
```

In essence this is just a `mapM id :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`, since for example for a 3-list, it is equal to:

```
-- special case for 3 elements to demonstrate how it works
func3 [a, b, c] = do
    ya <- a
    yb <- b
    yc <- c
    return [ya, yb, yc]
```

or thus like:

```
func3 [a, b, c] = a >>= \ya -> b >>= \yb -> c >>= yc -> return [ya, yb, yc]
```

(I here use a special case, since `mapM` introduces some extra functions making it harder to follow)

Since for `Maybe`, the `Monad Maybe` is implemented like:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
    (Just x) >>= f = f x
```

so that means that from the moment one of the elements (`a`, `b` or `c`) is `Nothing`, the result will be `Nothing`, if all values are `Just`s, we will "collect" these with the lambda expression, and eventually yield a list with the elements.

You can see a list `[]` as a generalization of a `Maybe` (where `Nothing` is the empty list, and `Just` is a singleton list), and the same behavior can be observed:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [[1,2], [4,3]]
[[1,4],[1,3],[2,4],[2,3]]
Prelude Control.Monad> sequence [[1,2], [4,3], []]
[]
```

Here `sequence` will make a *cross product*, but if one of the lists that provide the elements of one of the set for which we apply a cross product is empty, the result is empty as well.

Comment: Thank you Willem!! Now I understand sequence does mapM id [Maybe a]